# How to solve this questions about regular surfaces?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I'm trying to solve the following:

$i)$ Show that if all normals to a connected surface pass trough a fixed point, the surface is contained in a sphere.

$ii)$ Prove that if a regular surface $S$  meets a plane $P$ in a single point $p$, then this plane coincides with the tangent plane of $S$ at $p$.

$iii)$ Let $S\subset \mathbb{R^3}$ be a regular surface and $P\subset \mathbb{R^3}$ be a plane. If all points of $S$ are on the same side of $P$, prove that $P$ is tangent to $S$ at all points of $P\cap S$.

The second one is intuitive but I don't know how to proceed. For the other two I have to say that I don't know how to start. I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very nice questions indeed!

Change of notation:  the surface will be denoted by $\Sigma$ instead of $S$, and the plane by $\Pi$ instead $P$; this done since I had already written up a large portion of my answer employing this altered symbolism when I re-read the problem statement and re-discovered the OP's original use of $S$, $P$, etc.  Apologies for any confusion caused .

Let's handle the questions in the order asked:

*i.*)  Suppose $\Sigma$ is a connected surface in $\Bbb R^3$; then $\Sigma$, being a $2$-manifold, is path connected.  (See [this web page](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node140.html) and the citings therein.)  Let $p, q \in \Sigma$ be any two points, and let $\gamma:[0, 1] \to \Sigma$ be a smooth path joining $p$ and $q$ in the sense that $\gamma(0) = p$, $\gamma(1) = q$.  Then by the given hypothesis, the normal line at every point of $\gamma(t)$ contains the same point $Q$; thus the vector $\gamma(t) - Q$ is normal to $\Sigma$ at $\gamma(t)$ for all $t \in [0, 1]$.  Since $\gamma(t)$ is a curve in $\Sigma$, its tangent vectors $\dot \gamma(t)$ are each orthogonal to $\gamma(t) - Q$; i.e.

$\dot \gamma(t) \cdot (\gamma(t) - Q) = 0 \tag{1}$

for all $t \in [0, 1]$.  $Q$ being fixed, we have

$\dot Q = \dfrac{dQ}{dt} = 0, \tag{2}$

whence

$\dot \gamma(t) = (\gamma(t) - Q)'; \tag{3}$

here I switch freely 'twixt the "dot" (as in $\dot \gamma$) and "prime" (as in $\gamma'$) notation for derivatives, depending on which is easiest to write in a given expression.  In any event, if (3) is substituted into (1), we have

$(\gamma(t) - Q)' \cdot (\gamma(t) - Q) = 0 \tag{4}$

for all $t$, which in turn implies

$(\Vert \gamma(t) - Q \Vert^2)' = ((\gamma(t) - Q ) \cdot (\gamma(t) - Q))' = 2(\gamma(t) - Q)' \cdot (\gamma(t) - Q) = 0; \tag{5}$

i.e., $\Vert \gamma(t) - Q \Vert$ must be a constant independent of $t$.  Thus in fact we have

$\Vert p - Q \Vert = \Vert \gamma(0) - Q \Vert = \Vert \gamma(1) - Q \Vert = \Vert q - Q \Vert = \Vert \gamma(t) - Q \Vert \tag{6}$

for all $t \in [0, 1]$.  Since $p, q \in \Sigma$ are arbitrary, we see that every point of $\Sigma$ lies at a distance $\Vert p - Q \Vert$ from $Q$; $\Sigma$ thus lies in the sphere if radius $\Vert p - Q \Vert$  centered at $Q$.  ***QED.***

*ii.*)  We will prove this one by contraposition; that is, we will show that, if $\Pi$ is any plane intersecting $\Sigma$ at $p$ non-tangentially, then in any neighborhood $U \subset \Sigma$ of $p$ there is a regular curve $\gamma:(-\epsilon, \epsilon) \to \Sigma \cap \Pi$, for some $0 \ne \epsilon \in \Bbb R$ with $\gamma(0) = p$; the existence such $\gamma(t)$ then implies not merely that there are more than one points of intersection of $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$, but that there are in fact an uncoutable infinity of them, all within $U$.  The proof proceeds as follows:  let $p \in U \subset \Sigma$, with $U$ a sufficiently small open set that a smooth unit normal field $N_\Sigma$ to $\Sigma$ is defined everywhere on $U$.  Clearly, if $\Sigma$ is orientable, we can take $U$ to be all of $\Sigma$, but in any event, $U$ may always be taken to be diffeomophic to an open disk in $\Bbb R^2$.  Next, we observe that $\Pi$, being a plane, is itself possessed of a *constant* unit normal field $N_\Pi$, and that indeed the equation of the plane $\Pi$ may be written

$(r - \pi) \cdot N_\Pi = 0, \tag{7}$

where $\pi \in \Pi$ is any fixed point, and $r =(x, y, z)$ represents the coordinates of a variable point in $\Pi$.  As is well-known, (7) presents the equation of a plane passing through point $\pi$ with normal vector $N_\Pi$; taking $\pi$ to be $p$, we obtain the equation of the plane with normal $N_\Pi$ passing through the point $p \in \Sigma$:

$(r - p) \cdot N_\Pi = 0.  \tag{8}$

If $\Pi$ is not tangent to $\Sigma$ at $p$, then $N_\Pi$ is not collinear with $N_\Sigma(p)$,  which implies that

$N_\Pi \times N_\Sigma(p) \ne 0. \tag{9}$

Now consider the smooth vector field $X$ on $U$ defined by

$X(q) = N_\Pi \times N_\Sigma (q) \tag{10}$

for $q \in U$.  In defining $X(q)$ *via* (10), we simply extend $N_\Pi$ to all of $\Bbb R^3$; in so doing, it is defined at every point of $\Sigma$ to be the same, constant vector.  Inspecting the definition (10), we see that

$X(q) \cdot N_\Sigma (q) = (N_\Pi \times N_\Sigma(q)) \cdot N_\Sigma(q) = 0 \tag{11}$

and

$X(q) \cdot N_\Pi = (N_\Pi \times N_\Sigma (q)) \cdot N_\Pi = 0, \tag{12}$

since the vector cross product is always orthogonal to each of its arguments.  (11) shows that $X(q)$ is in fact tangent to $\Sigma$ at all points $q$ at which it is defined; furthermore, since $X(q)$ is smooth and nonzero at $q = p$, we can if necessary, by taking $U$ to be an even smaller neighborhood of $p$, insure that $X(q)$ is nonzero for all $q \in U$.  This being the case, and since $X(q)$ being smooth implies it is (locally, at least) Lipschitz continuous, for any $q \in U$ there is an $\epsilon > 0$, an open interval $I _\epsilon = (-\epsilon, \epsilon) \subset \Bbb R$, and a smooth curve $\gamma(q, t): I_\epsilon \to U$ with $\gamma(q, 0) = q$ and

$\dot \gamma(q, t) = X(\gamma(q, t)); \tag{13}$

that is, $\gamma(q, t)$ is the unique solution to the differential equation (13) with $\gamma(q, 0) = q$.  Taking $q = p$, we have $\gamma(p, t) \subset U$ and $\gamma(p, 0) = p$.  By (12) and (13), we see that

$\dot \gamma(p, t) \cdot N_\Pi = X(\gamma(p, t)) \cdot N_\Pi = 0, \tag{14}$

and this implies that

$((\gamma(p, t) - p) \cdot N_\Pi)' = \dot \gamma(p, t) \cdot N_\Pi =0, \tag{15}$

since $p$ and $N_\Pi$ are constants.  (15) shows that $(\gamma(p, t) - p) \cdot N_\Pi$ is constant, and since

$(\gamma(p,   0) - p) \cdot N_\Pi = (p - p) \cdot N_\Pi = 0, \tag{16}$

we have that

$(\gamma(p, t) - p) \cdot N_\Pi = 0 \tag{17}$

for all $t$ in $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon > 0$.  (17) implies the curve $\gamma(p, t)$ lies in the plane $\Pi$; thus it lies in the intersection $\Sigma \cap \Pi$ of the surface $\Sigma$ and the plane $\Pi$; since as we have seen $\dot \gamma(p, t) = X(\gamma(p, t)) \ne 0$ in $U$, $\gamma(p, t)$ is regular, the image of $\gamma(p, t)$ in $\Sigma \cap \Pi$ contains an uncountable infinity of distinct points.

We have just shown that if $\Pi$ is *not* tangent to $\Sigma$ at $p$, then $\Pi \cap \Sigma$ contains the regular curve $\gamma(p, t)$, hence is uncountable.  So if we assume that $\Pi \cap \Sigma = \{ p \}$ a singleton, then we must have $\Pi$ tangent to $\Sigma$ at $p$.  ***QED.***

***Note:***  It may also be possible to prove this, that is, the existence of $\gamma(p, t)$ (or perhaps even $\gamma(q, t)$, $q \ne p$), using the implicit function theorem, but I haven't got it completely figured out as of this writing.  ***End of Note.***

(*iii.*)  To answer this question, one needs to adopt some definition or other of just what it means for a point to be on one side or the other of a plane.  For the present purposes I will deploy a definition based upon equation (7); consider the function

$h(r) = (r - \pi) \cdot N_\Pi, \tag{18}$

where $\pi \in \Pi$ is a specified (non-variable) point and $r \in \Bbb R^3$.  It is easy to see that

$\nabla h = N_\Pi, \tag{19}$

everywhere the same.  We have also seen that $h(r) = 0$ for $r \in \Pi$, ; this may be interpreted as saying that the line segment or "vector" from $\pi$ to $r$ is in fact perpendicular to $N_\Pi$.  If, on the other hand, $h(r) > 0$, then $r - \pi$ has a *positive* component in the $N_\Pi$ direction, similarly if $h(r) < 0$, then such a component is *negative*.  Since

$h(r)= (r - \pi) \cdot N_\Pi = r \cdot N_\Pi - \pi \cdot N_\Pi, \tag{20}$

and $r \cdot N_\Pi$, $\pi \cdot N_\Pi$ are the respective distances of $r$, $\pi$ from the origin  in the direction $N_\Pi$ , we see that $h(r)$ is in fact the excess distance, along $N_\Pi$, of $r$ over $\pi$ from the point $(0, 0, 0)$.  I don't want to go into much more detail about this here an now, since these remarks I *have* made concerning $h(r)$ are really part of elementary $3$-space geometry, almost at the high-school level; I re-iterate them here in order to convey a mathematically formal yet clear understanding of what is meant by being on one side of the plane $\Pi$ or the other.  These things being (hopefully adequately) explained, we may proceed.  We will say a point $r$ is on the *positive* side of $\Pi$ provided that $h(r) \ge 0$, and on the *negative* side if $h(r) \le 0$.  We allow $h(r) = 0$ in this terminology to cover the possibility that $\Sigma \cap \Pi \ne \emptyset$, as in the statement of the problem.  These matters being settled, suppose then that $\Sigma$ lies on the positive side of $\Pi$.  Then $h(\sigma) \ge 0$ for any $\sigma \in \Sigma$.  If $\gamma(u)$ is a smooth path in $\Sigma$, then

$(h(\gamma(u)))'_{u = u_0} = (\gamma'(u_0)[h(\gamma(u))])_{u = u_0} = \langle \gamma'(u_0), \nabla H(u_0) \rangle = \langle \gamma'(u_0), N_\Pi \rangle. \tag{21}$

Now if $\sigma \in \Sigma \cap \Pi$, then $h(\sigma) = 0$ so if $\gamma(u_0) = \sigma$, then $h(\gamma(u)) \ge h(\gamma(u_0))$ for all $u$, we must, by the standard result from calculus on derivatives of single variable functions at local extrema, have

$0 = (h(\gamma(u)))'_{u = u_0} = \langle \gamma'(u_0), N_\Pi \rangle. \tag{22}$

But any tangent vector to $\Sigma$ at $\sigma$ is given by $\gamma'(u_0)$ for some path $\gamma(u)$ with $\gamma(u_0) = \sigma$; this shows the entire tangent plane to $\Sigma$ at $\sigma$ is normal to $N_\Pi$; hence it must in fact be $\Pi$.  ***QED.***

***Note:*** The above results all generalize nicely to the case of $\Sigma$ an $n$ dimensional hypersurface in $\Bbb R^{n + 1}$; the proofs of (*i*) and (*iii*) need very little change to do so; as for (*ii*), if $n \ge 3$ we of course cannot use (10), since the cross product $\times$ is not defined in this case.  But we can in fact find a vector field $X$ tangent to $\Sigma$ in $U$, with $X \cdot N_\Sigma = X \cdot N_\Pi = 0$, simply by taking $X$ to be a non-vanishing section the sub-bundle of $T\Bbb R^{n + 1}$ on $U$ which is normal to both $N_\Sigma$ and $N_\Pi$; then $X$ is a section of $TU$ and the above above argument extends virtually unaltered.  By taking $U$ sufficiently small, it is straighforward to present such an $X$ in terms of local coordinates in $U$.  ***End of Note.***

Hope this helps!  Holiday Cheers,

and as ever,

***Fiat Lux!!!***